# How to get the whole sentence for title of <a> tag using <%= t('vote.up') %> in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

In en.yml, `vote.up = "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"`
When I write:

```
<a href="#" title=<%= t('vote.up') %> ><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
```

I get the HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="This" question="" does="" not="" show="" any="" research="" effort;="" it="" is="" unclear="" or="" useful=""><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
```

But I hope to get:

```
<a href="#" title="This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
```

How should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `title`'s html attribute value in double quotes:

```
title="<%= t('vote.up') %>"
```